# How can I empty my Camera Roll from my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, camera

I don't want to save anything—just wipe out the Roll like one would reformat a digital camera's memory card. Is there any easy non-computer route? If there aren't any system settings, do any apps do this?

Assume I have too many to delete individually (1,000+).

Comment: Why don't you just delete them via the photos app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't an easy way to do so. As far as I know, there is no app which can do what you want... So I've come up with two alternative solutions.

The most easy one is to connect your iPhone to your Mac, launch [Image Capture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_Capture) (which comes by default on your Mac), select all the photos and delete them. Here is [a tutorial](http://www.wondershare.com/disk-utility/delete-camera-roll.html) how to do so.

You can do this on your iPhone as well, without a Mac, but you'll have to do it manually. Which isn't a grateful job if you've got over a 1,000 photos...

Open the camera app, hit the upper-right icon (share), tap all the photos you want to delete (they are marked with a red check-icon) and then hit delete.

[image] 
[image]

Comment: Great tip about using Image Capture!

Comment: Ok, this worked great, thanks. Not complaining, just asking, when I sync my phone and iPhoto offers to import/delete, why isn't this already taken care of? How is this set of photos not already gone?

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature to do this with one tap. With the advent of iCloud photos, you could conceivably enroll in that to convert the camera roll into cloud backed storage and once that processing is done, sign out of iCloud / disable photos on that device.

To start, make a backup of your phone (just in case iCloud fails you) and then open the settings app. Go to iCloud and then tap on Photos. Enable **iCloud Photo Library** and then connect to a fast WiFi network to allow all the photos to be removed from the camera roll.

It's not going to be faster than connecting to a computer in 99% of the time, but for the stated goal of doing it all without a computer, it's now possible.